# R zip package isn't extracting files because of encoding error

Tags: r, encoding, unzip

I've made a loop to extract some zip file inside same name diretory, using unzip package.
But unzip isn't recognizing UTF-8 encoding.

See below:

> arquivos.1[i]

[1] "CONCEIÇÃO DO MATO DENTRO - CONVITE 530-S07255.zip"

> unzip(arquivos.1[i])

Error in unzip(arquivos.1[i]) :
zip error: `Cannot open zip file` E:\1\scrape\CONCEIÃ‡ÃƒO DO MATO DENTRO - CONVITE 530-S07255.zip `for reading` in file `zip.c:238`

Comment: Perhaps an issue with the Unicode filepath.  From `help(unzip)`, try setting `unzip = "unzip"` and make sure your version of the `unzip` utility is greater than 6.0.0.

Comment: It doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Solution: I had to rename the files to extract the symbols (ÇÃ) and later unzip.